# String contains or regex in pawn scripting language

Tags: regex, string, pawn

or example

```
if(playerName.Contains("<") || playerName.Contains("-")){

}
```

or how i can check string with regex pattern(^[-0-9A-Za-z_]{5,15}$)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are saying that the string should contain at least a - or a < right? Than it's

```
(^(?=.*[-<])[-0-9A-Za-z_<]{5,15}$)
```

The technique of lookaround is used to make this possible

Comment: yeas you are right but how i can check if string matches on this regex pattern in pawn language. I need it for amx mod x